# Derivative of Volume of Cone with Respect to Time

Tags: calculus, derivatives, implicit-differentiation

Find the equation for the rate of change of the volume V, where $V=\frac{1}{3}\pi r^2 h$ and the radius r and the height h are both functions of time t.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess you're looking for this...
$$\frac{dV}{dt}=\frac{1}{3}\pi\frac{d(r^2h)}{dt}$$
$$\frac{dV}{dt}=\frac{1}{3}\pi(2rh\frac{dr}{dt}+r^2\frac{dh}{dt})$$